# Twitter bootstrap with font instead of images?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, icons

I don't want to use image file in 'icon-*' class, because we can not increase the size of that image, if we do so obviously. Is there any library which uses font to support the same icons with same classes?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). I think it will provide what you are looking for.